# Fill Chart.js Doughnut Chart dynamically with data through jquery ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, charts, chart.js

I try to get two values out of database in a chart.js doughnut chart. 
Unfortunately it won't work. The values are properly provided from the database to my webpage but chart.js does not use them.

I defined two global vars:

```
var doughnutfail = 50;
var doughnutsuccess = 50;
```

I get data by:

```
function getdynamicdata(){
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'fill-chart.php',
          async: false,
          success: function(result) {
            var returning= JSON.parse(result);
            $('#failwert').html(returning[0]+"%");
            $('#successwert').html(returning[1]+"%");
            $('#totalwert').html(returning[2]+" Tage");
            doughnutfail = returning[0];
            doughnutsuccess = returning[1];

            updateChartData(doughnutfail, doughnutsuccess);

          },
      });
    }
```

then I create the new DataVar:

```
function  updateChartData(failin, successin){

           var fail=failin;
           var success=successin;

           var doughnutData = [
                {
                    value: fail,
                    color:"#1bbc9d"
                },
                {
                    value : success,
                    color : "#e84c3d"
                }
            ]; 

      }
```

The chart is called by:

```
var myDoughnut = new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d")).Doughnut(doughnutData);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Move your `new Chart...` code inside the `updateChartData` function

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your reply. Unfortunately that does not help :-( I placed the new Chart in the updateChartData function. If I place an alert right before the doughnutData it contains the right values but my graph does not show up. If I replace the values with static float numbers it all works great :-(

Comment: What are values of `failin` and `successin` variables? Also don't use alerts, use Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools.

Comment: damn it, found the problem: I was getting strings and after phrasing them into floats all works great. :-)